# Rails: Method returns object instead of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm in the process of building my first Rails application and am going crazy knowing this is probably a simple fix. I'm having trouble returning the proper object and attribute from a method. I have three models: User, Feed and Subscription.

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :feeds, through: :subscriptions

  def subscribe!(feed_id)
    subscriptions.create!(feed_id: feed.id)
  end
end
```

Subscription:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :feed, class_name: "Feed"

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :feed_id, presence: true
end
```

Feed:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
  belongs_to :subscriptions

  def self.create_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)

    unless exists? :feed_url => feed.url
      create!(
        :title => feed.title,
        :feed_url => feed.feed_url,
        :url => feed.url,
        :etag => feed.etag,
        :last_modified=> feed.last_modified
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever I call user.subscriptions.create!(feed) explicitly from the console it works just fine, but the test using it don't pass. The test in question:

```
describe "subscribing" do
  let(:feed) { Feed.create_feed("http://www.somevalidfeed.com/feed/") }
  before { @user.subscribe!(feed) }
end
```

This returns:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `feed' for #<User:0x007f9c951b3b98>
```

I don't understand why this is returning an object or why it's trying to find the id of the User instead of the Feed object that's being passed to it. After searching for a few hours I just can't seem to get pointed in the right direction, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `User` class, I think your subscribe method is wrong, it should be

```
def subscribe!(feed)
  subscriptions.create!(feed_id: feed.id)
end
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like this! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

probably here's the problem:

```
  def subscribe!(feed_id)
    subscriptions.create!(feed_id: feed.id)
  end
```

probably you meant

```
  def subscribe!(feed_id)
    subscriptions.create!(feed_id: feed_id)
  end
```

or even

```
  def subscribe!(feed)
    subscriptions.create!(feed_id: feed.id)
  end
```